# Weird MethodNotFound exception when renaming a property - related to asp.net / web forms / fluentnhibernate and visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, methodnotfound

I have a local website which I run through Visual Studio 2008's internal development web server (through the run / compile button).

I have an external library which is referenced on a page of that website and resides inside the web site's "bin" folder.

I've recently changed a class' property name inside that library (renaming it, from "ValidFrom" to "VisibleFrom"), recompiled its dll and have overwritten the original dll inside the bin folder.

This class is mapped with FluentNHibernate, I've also changed the mappings and recompiled / redeployed the library.

When I try to run the site and navigate to the page where the library is used, I'm getting a *MethodNotFound* exception for the method *get_ValidFrom*, related to FluentNHibernate's configuration call. This should be *get_VisibleFrom* now!

Now I've reconfigured my NHibernate SessionProvider so that it generates a new Configuration for NHibernate on each call, and does not retrieve it from the Http Session entity like it did before, because I figured there might lie the problem.

I'm still getting the exception however. I've then deleted the Temporary ASP.NET folder's content... but I'm still getting the error.

Where is the generated schema for NHibernate stored, when using FluentNHibernate?

Anyone knows where else this could somehow be cached?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FNH does not cache the schema, it is generated on-the-fly when you make a call to `Fluently.Configure()` and the schema is passed directly into an NHibernate `Configuration` object which is used to build an `ISessionFactory`.

Try clearing out all compiled objects/libraries/executables, removing the reference to your library from all projects that use it, add it back in, and then re-compile everything. Also check your all your code for "magic strings" that may be referencing this property or causing it to be referenced by the old name.

If that doesn't work, it might be helpful to see a stack trace to get an idea of what is being called from where.